# Do we really require to have instance template and instance group to create HTTP load balancer in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have created two virtual machines and want to use load balancer having these two virtual machines.

But I could see GCP is insisting to creating template first and then instance group. But I am looking for something without the creation of template, since I already have two virtual machine to be used by the load balancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a template if you use an "Unmanaged instance group", but yo do need to create an unmanaged instance group to use a load balancer.

[Creating groups of unmanaged instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances)

Comment: @Kampassi - When you receive an answer that solves your problem, click the accept button so that the question is not left unsolved.